# Angular 2 Updating values inside an ngFor with a promise is not showing the proper values

Tags: angular, typescript, promise, ngfor

I get a first list of elements which I show in the view from a service. But after I get the the array I need to update the inner elements with the results of new promises but this is not working. Please see the attached plnkr for to see the issue.
This is the service access:

```
this.teamsService.getTeams()
  .then(teams=> {
    teams.forEach(team => team.name = 
    this.namesService.getName(idx++));
    this.teams = teams
  });
```

This is the view:

```
<div *ngFor="let team of teams">
  <p>Team {{team.name.value}}</p> 
</div>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/TWyv7DbPyQjehzAs457P?p=info

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are trying to bind promises directly to the view, and it doesnt work like that because "something" needs to resolve these promises to get the results.. Angular has a pipe called "async" for resolving observables and promises, so I edited your plunkr here using the async pipe which will resolve the names. Also that idx should start from 1 instead of 0 I guess because your array of names does not have any teams with id == 0. 
Your main problem was this part

```
{{(team.name | async)?.value}}
```

Here it is https://plnkr.co/edit/BdzvLBYNjD3LB2GjrAKe?p=preview